# How the previous thread starts again when we use Thread's join method

Tags: java, multithreading

When we use join method in thread the currently running thread gets stopped and the another threads starts working with a condition that the first thread will again start running once the second one completes its job. How this can be done? How second thread passes object lock to first thread?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the implementation

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0); // timeout of 0 means forever
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

So the current `Thread` just calls `wait()` on the other `Thread` while the other `Thread` hasn't finished, ie. `isAlive()` still returns `true`.

Note that the method is `synchronized`, otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by

> How second thread passes object lock to first thread?

When you call `wait()` however, you release the object monitor, so some third `Thread` can also `join()` on this `Thread`.

Additional details by [zch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944431/how-the-previous-thread-starts-again-when-we-use-threads-join-method/18944459#comment27974765_18944459):

> The `join()` method waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread
>   to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever. This implementation uses
>   a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread
>   terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended
>   that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread
>   instances. This cannot be done without system support (except for
>   busy waiting).

Comment: Thanks for sharing implementation. By object lock passing i meant that, once second thread fnishes its work, how come first thread starts its work on the same object in a synchronized method.

Comment: I would add the comment: "Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever.

This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. **As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked**. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances." This cannot be done without system support (except for busy waiting).